# Pre-push git hook isn't picked up

Tags: git, git-bash, githooks

I'm trying to get the pre-push git hook to work. I can run it from git bash just fine, it just doesn't get picked up when I'm pushing. Am I doing something wrong?

File is ".git\hooks\pre-push"

File type is: Shell Script (.sh)

File contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "*****Running pre-push******"
```

Results, when running from git bash:

$ ./pre-push.sh

*****Running pre-push******

Comment: it needs to not have a file extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. Make sure pre-push doesn't have an extension. The file should just be called `pre-push`, with no `.sh` at the end. Bash knows it's a shell script because of the '#!/bin/sh'.
2. Configure the hooks path to be `.git/hooks`:

   ```sh
   git config core.hooksPath .git/hooks
   ```

Once you run this second step, everything should work like normal. You can also configure in globally to be `.git/hooks` if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks so much! I deleted the .sh extension, and git picked it up after that. It is shown in windows explorer just as "File" now, instead of "Shell Script", not sure, if that's normal, but it finally works, thanks!